# how to parse a non-string column as datetime with pandas.read_csv

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

My problem is this: I have a `.csv` file like this:

```
TS,secs,degC,Pa,V,V,V,V,V,degC,%
2019-08-29 15:29:02.000,0.000,23.21,97707.95,2.37942,4.06958,1.16183,2.06545,2.16861,22.70,53.70,
2019-08-29 15:29:04.000,2.001,23.22,98000.81,2.30359,4.04178,1.15457,2.06375,2.16660,22.70,54.00,
```

What i want to do is to parse the first column `TS` as datetime, but in my `.csv` file the first column is not a string. The code that I tried is as follows:

```
DATA = pd.read_csv('file.csv',sep=',',parse_dates=[0])
```

But the error that I obtain is this:

```
TypeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute '__getitem__'
```

Is there a way to parse a column without the `" "` as a datetime using pandas.read_csv? I'm open to other approach too, but the final result should be a pandas dataframe with the first column as datetime format.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just changing input data works as you expects
(Removing comma in end.)

Data:

```
TS,secs,degC,Pa,V,V,V,V,V,degC,%
2019-08-29 15:29:02.000,0.000,23.21,97707.95,2.37942,4.06958,1.16183,2.06545,2.16861,22.70,53.70
2019-08-29 15:29:04.000,2.001,23.22,98000.81,2.30359,4.04178,1.15457,2.06375,2.16660,22.70,54.00
```

and read as below mentioned:

```
df=pd.read_csv('file.csv', parse_dates=['TS'])
```

and `df.dtypes` gives desired output

```
TS        datetime64[ns]
secs             float64
degC             float64
Pa               float64
V                float64
V.1              float64
V.2              float64
V.3              float64
V.4              float64
degC.1           float64
%                float64
dtype: object
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that the first column with date content is parsed as an index column. In order to parse it in a datetime format you need to do following:

```
DATA = pd.read_csv('file.csv', sep=',')
DATA.index = pd.to_datetime(DATA.index)
```

then your index column will be of a datetime format:

```
DATA.index
DatetimeIndex(['2019-08-29 15:29:02', '2019-08-29 15:29:04'], dtype = 'datetime64[ns]', freq=None)
```